# Can a 802.11b router (D-Link 600M) fully utilize 100Mbps broadband connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I'm getting a broadband connection with 100Mbps speed. I already have a "D-link 600M" router. Should I pay and take the router the ISP are providing or I can use what I already have?

Comment: Just an FYI, unless that router is running opensource firmware, such as [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/toh/start?dataflt%5BBrand*%7E%5D=d-link), it is **not secure** to use being as it's last firmware update was 7 years ago _(i.e. it's missing 7yrs of security patches, which number in the hundreds, likely thousands)_.  All versions of the DIR-600 are supported by OpenWrt, so it would be recommended to flash OpenWrt first prior to using.

Answer (score 1):

The
[DIR-600M Wireless N 150 Home Router](https://dlinkmea.com/index.php/product/details?det=Z3lqcWxTdDVBcmpoakc4cUZjemo5Zz09)
is not just an 802.11b router, it is an 802.11**b/g/n** router which
is rated to up to 150 Mbps, so it is fast enough.

However, it is only a router and not a modem, so you still need the modem of the
ISP. This router can then be connected to the modem to better distribute
the internet connection to your devices.